# Is there an efficient way to check the usage for PV/PVC in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

For example, I have 50 Gib PV/PVC and grant to one Pod, I just want to check usage of the storage

The way I am just following is to set up a **busybox** pod with mounting the same PVC, then exec into the **busybox** to run `df -h` to check the storage.

I just want to know if there is an efficient way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Depending on how often you need to do this you might look at the `df-pv` plugin for `kubectl` https://github.com/yashbhutwala/kubectl-df-pv

It does exactly what you are asking across all the pvs in a namespace or cluster. Once you've got it installed, just run `kubectl df-pv` and you are set.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately we don't have this at the moment. What I often do is querying on Prometheus (because I have a Prom cluster there) for the metrics `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes` for the information.

Or in the harder way, you can write an operator to watch a CRD which wraps the PVC and to display the usage of the PVC.

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of PV-s (e.g. various cloud storage). Each of them might have a different way of getting this information. You could always use `kubectl describe pv <pv-name>` or `kubectl get pv <pv-name> -o yaml`. This might give you some information about the current state of the PV, but it might lack the information you need.

I assume though that you are using Local PV-s. In this case your solution to run `df -h` inside a container is not bad. One other thing you could do is to run this command on the node which hosts the PV directly.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually the describe donot have usage storage.
and I didnt use the Local PV, I am using the azure stroage. due to busybox is linux base, so the ```df -h``` could check the mount folder in busybox as my knowledge

Comment: You could also monitor your storage account in Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/.

Comment: yes, your correct. but as to company i am working on, the PaaS on azure are not visibility to devops, so I am just seeking a way in k8s.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below set of commands, I checked on AKS and found out it to be working fine.

```
kubectl get pods -n namespace1
```

Pick the pod_name currently using or mapped to the PV/PVC (Persistent Volume Claims) and since I used the mount directory on the PV hence I have used /mount to check its details & replace `{pod_name}` with actual pod_name.

```
kubectl exec -it {pod_name} -n namespace1 bash

df -h

ls -l /mount
```